# Restriction on city dropdown on checkout of woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, field, dropdown, city

down to the city checkout field on Woocommerce using the following code:

```html
function change_city_to_dropdown( $fields ) {
 include('citynames.php');
 
 $city_args = wp_parse_args( 'citydelivery' , array(
  'type' => 'select',
  'options' => array_combine( $cities, $cities),
  'input_class' => array(
   'wc-enhanced-select',
  )
 ), $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] );
 $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $city_args;
 $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = $city_args;
 wc_enqueue_js( "
  jQuery( ':input.wc-enhanced-select' ).filter( ':not(.enhanced)' ).each( function() {
   var select2_args = { minimumResultsForSearch: 5 };
   jQuery( this ).select2( select2_args ).addClass( 'enhanced' );
  });"
 );
 return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_city_to_dropdown' );
```

This does the job perfectly but I am unable to put a restriction on it. For eg the default value is "Select your city" but sometimes the customer doesn't select their city and order gets placed. I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```html
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'checkout_field_city_restriction()');
 function checkout_field_city_restriction() {
    global $woocommerce;
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ($_POST[$city_args] == "Select your city")
     wc_add_notice( '<strong>Please select your city</strong>', 'error' );
 }
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Also, this file ('citynames.php') has the following code:

```html
<?php

$cities = array(

'Select your city',
'Tall',
'Tando Jam',
'Topi',
'Pasni',
'Mastung',
'Kalat',
'Kamalia',
'Haroonabad',
'Ranipur',
 );
?>
```

Comment: What's in `$_POST[$city_args]`?

Comment: The cities that pass in the argument

Comment: anyone willing to help?

Comment: I will ask you again.. What's in `$_POST[$city_args]`?

Comment: Its a post method to post an argument that takes in cities. I am guessing the solution is around this code. I tried changing it from $_POST[$city_args] to $city_args but it didn't work.

Comment: If you don't know what's the value of `$_POST[$city_args]` then how would you test `$_POST[$city_args] == "Select your city"`? Use `var_dump($_POST[$city_args])` to find out what you have and then fix your code. Know how to debug, otherwise you will always have simple problems like this one.

Comment: I found out the values go into field 'billing_city' so I tried to change the code to:

$_POST['billing']['billing_city'] == "Select your city"

But this didn't impose any restriction. Am I writing the billing city correctly?

Comment: I solved it @FelippeDuarte. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

This is the following that had to be done:

```
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'checkout_field_city_restriction()');
 function checkout_field_city_restriction {
 global $woocommerce;
 // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
 if ($_POST[$billing_city] == "Select your city")
 wc_add_notice( '<strong>Please select your city</strong>', 'error' );
 }
```